# Displaying negative values on barchart

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create a chart where I can display a points difference for teams. Obviously some teams have negative points differences, while some teams have positive points differences.

The code I'm using is:

```
myRectangle.enter()
    .append("rect")
    .attr("x", function(d, i) {
        return 45 + i\*50;
        })
    .attr("y", function(d) {
        if (d.Pts\_diff < 0) {return 800 +(-1)\*d.Pts\_diff};
        else {return 400 - d.Pts\_diff;}
        })
    .attr("width", 45)
    .attr("height", function(d) {
        return d.Pts\_diff;
    .attr("fill", function(d) {
        if (d.Pts\_diff > 300) {return "red";}
        else if (d.Pts\_diff > 200) {return "orange";}
        else if (d.Pts\_diff > 100) {return "yellow";}
        else if (d.Pts\_diff > 0) {return "green";}
        else if (d.Pts\_diff > -100) {return "blue";}
        else {return "purple;"}
        })
    })
```

When I do that I get an error saying that I have an unexpected token "else".

Any suggestions?

Comment: `\*` and `\_` are not valid javascript (unless they're inside a string/regex). Also you have a stray `;` after the first `if` block. That seems to be the source of the `unexpected token "else"`

Comment: I have no idea why it is being translated that way. They should be ````d.Pts_diff````

Answer (score 2):

I suppose your problem is this line

```
if (d.Pts\_diff < 0) {return 800 +(-1)\*d.Pts\_diff};
```

You have an extra ";" at the end, because next line starts with `else`.
Remove semicolon

Comment: Thanks, no idea how I missed that

Comment: No problem. It happens (a lot).